# How to add an Object as an Excel row using C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop

I have a class say for instance - Member which looks like

```
class Member
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string AddDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }            
}
```

Now I need to insert and Object of Member as a Row into an Excel sheet. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop` and have a WorkSheet object by using the code below:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
```

My final output should look like 
[image]

Comment: I usually build up an `array` with the properties in the order to write to Excel, you could use a `string` array since all your properties are of the same type. Next I'll get a `Range` from the `Worksheet` from the first column that I wish to write to until `array.Length - 1`. With this `Range` I'll set it's `.Value2` property to the created array.

Answer (score 3):

Well you've already declared your `Excel.Worksheet`, now you just need to iterate over your `Member` classes that are stored somewhere and write each of their properties into the worksheet.

Assuming you have all `Member` classes stored in a `List<Member> members` and all header values in a `List<string> headers`:

```
//Setting up headers

int column = 1;
foreach (var item in members)
    xlWorksheet.Cells[1, column++].Value = item;

//setting up member values

int row = 2;
foreach (var item in members)
{
    column = 1;
    xlWorksheet.Cells[row, column++].Value = item.Id;
    xlWorksheet.Cells[row, column++].Value = item.Login;
    xlWorksheet.Cells[row, column++].Value = item.AddDate;
    xlWorksheet.Cells[row, column++].Value = item.FirstName;
    xlWorksheet.Cells[row, column++].Value = item.LastName;
    xlWorksheet.Cells[row++, column].Value = item.FullName;
}
```

Please note that this might not be the optimal solution if you're dealing with crazy big amounts of data that needs to be inserted into the worksheet. In that case you could disable excel's screenupdating (`xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;`), however, please note that you should enable it back to `true` after you're done with your insertion. I think in your case the simplicity of my code will work just fine, but if you absolutely must optimize it, then you could also insert an array of `Member` directly by using `Value2` of the `Excel.Range`. Something like this:

```
const int rowCount = 1, columnCount = 6;
object[,] membersArray = new object[rowCount, columnCount];
//fill up membersArray with your data here
xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value2 = membersArray;
```

Comment: PERFECT. WORKED WELL.